# Good Books on relations and functions

Tags: functions, reference-request, relations

What are the books you would recommend to starters on the topics of Relations and functions.

In your opinion why is this book better than the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how far you want to go I can point two books: 'Discrete mathematics with applications' by Sussanna S. Epp - this is good for beginners; the other is 'A book on set theory'  by Charles Pinter - it is more rigorous.